# wrapping 'rest_api_init' in 'is_admin()' function

Tags: wp-admin, rest-api, admin-menu

i'm create custom admin page via `add_menu_page`, let's imagine that my custom page has url

> wp-admin/admin.php?page=settings_page

then i'm checki `is_admin()` function via `var_dump` on my `settings_page` and it returns `true` - that's OK, but when i'm wrap `rest_api_init` action in `if is_admin()` statement, like this:

```
if(is_admin()){
  add_action('rest_api_init',   [$this, 'myRegisterRoutesFunction']);
}
```

it returns me `404 - No route was found matching the URL and request method`. But if i remove `if` statement, it works fine. Can't understand why, thanks for the advices!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, you shouldn't wrap your REST route declarations inside is_admin() since Wordpress will not load them (see @DarkNueron comment).

What you can do is pass a 'permission_callback' function to the `register_rest_route` function. If the function returns true, the request is allowed to continue; if false, an error is returned.

So you could do:

```php
register_rest_route('your-namespace/v1', '/options/', [
   'methods'   => 'PATCH',
   'callback'  => [__CLASS__, 'update_option'],
   'permission_callback'   => function () {
        return current_user_can('manage_options');
   }
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's due to the way WP initializes the REST endpoints. It works something like this:

Someone `POST`s to an endpoint, f.ex `/wp-json/my/custom/endpoint`. Wordpress tries to figure out if there is a route for that endpoint by calling the `rest_api_init` hook, and running any custom code that sets up that route.

Now check out the source for `is_admin`:

```
function is_admin() {
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['current_screen'] ) ) {
        return $GLOBALS['current_screen']->in_admin();
    } elseif ( defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
        return WP_ADMIN;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Nothing magical here, it just checks what screen you're currently on. However, there's no "screen" when a REST call comes in. So `is_admin` is always going to return false.

So thats what happens when you wrap your REST initialization logic with `is_admin`.